# How to script a Button press in C#, to trigger another event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, virtual-reality

I'm working on Unity, w/ Vuforia.

I've got Virtual buttons that I need to act like the Up/Down Arrows on the keyboard to move an object which is not in its image target, so I'm searching for the basics.

My class starts like this:

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
...
}
```

What do I need to put in this to make it act like the up button?

Without these virtual buttons, my script would move the object like this:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHortizonal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHortizonal, 0, moveVertical);

        rigidbody.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured out how to do it, and here's a small tutorial on my findings**

First of all, you start with registering the buttons:

```
void Start () {
        VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour> ();

        for (int i=0; i < vbs.Length; ++i) {
            vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }
```

And now you go ahead and start with the function of the button

```
   public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    //specify which button you want to function by using the if statement
    if(vb.name=="ButtonName") { callButtonfunction();}
    }
```

Similarly if you want a button to do something on release:

```
   public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    //specify which button you want to function by using the if statement
    if(vb.name=="ButtonName") { callButtonfunction();}
    }
```

In case you want your button to control a Gameobject, then go ahead and declare the GameObject as a public variable in the class so that it can be accessed in the Inspector and assigned accordingly.

`public GameObject human;`

Where `GameObject` is the variable type and `human` is the variable name that we use for reference

It's as simple as that.

> The Vuforia logs are very badly documented and so you can almost never
>   get an answer from there, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Found this very helpful! This isn't properly mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: You're very welcome :) And yes, Vuforia's documentation isn't the best.