# How to create virtual button to run URL using Vuforia and unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have developed an augmented reality project for android and I need to know how to use a virtual button to open a URL (website) in the application

thank you

Comment: any code ? something ? or you`re waiting for free solutions ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know how to start, if you have a tutorial or sample project, i need it

Answer (score 1):

After following the answer given [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977822/how-to-script-a-button-press-in-c-to-trigger-another-event) within the `OnButtonPressed()` function use the [**Application.OpenURL**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) function to get it through a URL. Use the documentation linked for anything else.

Below is an example of how you might want to go about it.

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb){
    //specify which button you want to function by using the if statement
    if(vb.name=="ButtonName") { 
      Application.OpenURL("http://www.xys.com/whateveryouwant")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.